# Pandas filter by date range within each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like:

[image]

and I have to filter my df by having values within two weeks from each ID
so for each ID, I have to look ahead next two weeks from the first date and only keep those records.

Output:

[image]

I tried creating a min date per each ID and using below code to try to filter:

```
df[df.date.between(df['min_date'],df['min_date']+pd.DateOffset(days=14))]
```

Is their any efficient way than this? because this is taking a lot of time since my dataframe is big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': np.repeat([2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 4]),
    'Date': ['12/31/2019', '1/1/2020', '1/5/2020', '1/20/2020',
             '1/5/2020', '1/10/2020', '1/30/2020', '2/2/2020',
             '2/4/2020', '2/10/2020', '2/25/2020'],
    'Value': [*'abcbdeefffg']
})
```

---

First, convert `Date` to `Timestamp` with `to_datetime`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

---

#### `concat` with `groupby` in a comprehension

```
pd.concat([
    d[d.Date <= d.Date.min() + pd.offsets.Day(14)]
    for _, d in df.groupby('Id')
])

   Id       Date Value
0   2 2019-12-31     a
1   2 2020-01-01     b
2   2 2020-01-05     c
4   3 2020-01-05     d
5   3 2020-01-10     e
7   4 2020-02-02     f
8   4 2020-02-04     f
9   4 2020-02-10     f
```

---

#### boolean slice... also with `groupby`

```
df[df.Date <= df.Id.map(df.groupby('Id').Date.min() + pd.offsets.Day(14))]

   Id       Date Value
0   2 2019-12-31     a
1   2 2020-01-01     b
2   2 2020-01-05     c
4   3 2020-01-05     d
5   3 2020-01-10     e
7   4 2020-02-02     f
8   4 2020-02-04     f
9   4 2020-02-10     f
```

Comment: I upvoted this because of the slicing answer. Can you explain what `map` does?

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with `pandas.concat`, so you can try using `merge`:

```py
# Convert Date to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Get min Date for each Id and add two weeks (14 days)
s = df.groupby('Id')['Date'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(14)

# Merge df and s
df = df.merge(s, left_on='Id', right_index=True)

# Keep records where Date is less than the allowed limit
df = df.loc[df['Date_x'] <= df['Date_y'], ['Id','Date_x','Value']]

# Rename Date_x to Date (optional)
df.rename(columns={'Date_x':'Date'}, inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
   Id       Date Value
0   2 2019-12-31     a
1   2 2020-01-01     b
2   2 2020-01-05     c
4   3 2020-01-05     d
5   3 2020-01-10     e
7   4 2020-02-02     f
8   4 2020-02-04     f
9   4 2020-02-10     f
```